# what is the best model that can be fitted onto a retention curve

Tags: curve-fitting

I have a retention curve from activity data from customers which trends from 100% on day 1 down towards 0% over team in a curve. I need to fit a model to extrapolate this data past what data I have.

What is the best model/method to use for this?

Comment: If its monotonic nondecreasing it sounds like a good candidate for parametric (or indeed perhaps nonparametric) survival models.

Comment: it would help if you posted an example of your data as we have seen data like this when analyzing the utilization of gift cards over time.

Comment: If the data trends down in a straight line, then a straight line model should work OK. Other than that, I have no data to work with here and cannot advise.